# How to show count values in Admin Dashboard of Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem about showing counts of all values.

I have no idea to show some values like the count of total users in the dashboard.
I tried to use entityManager.createQuery but I couldn't move forward.

How can I get its count?

What about getting other values?

Here are the code snippets shown below.

Here is the mainController shown below.

```
@GetMapping("")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
        DashboardInfo summary = dashboardService.loadSummary();
        model.addAttribute("summary", summary); 
        return "index";
    }
```

Here is the DashboardService shown below.

```
@Service
public class DashboardService {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    public DashboardInfo loadSummary() {
        DashboardInfo summary = new DashboardInfo();
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) AS totalUsers FROM User u)");
        // HOW TO DO THAT
        return summary;
    }
}
```

Here is the DashboardInfo class shown below.

```
public class DashboardInfo {
    private long totalUsers;
    private long totalCategories;
    private long totalBrands;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the query but you haven't executed it

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) AS totalUsers FROM User u)");

var count = (Long)query.getSingleResult();
```

Though I'd advise you to use repositories instead of the entity manager. Keeps things cleaner

Comment: I mentioned about some values like the count of total users, the count of total products. There is no single line query. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't really get what you're asking. The above query counts all the users. I guess if you want all the products, you query the same but on the products table.  "There is no single line query" what do you mean?

Comment: I mean `.createQuery("(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) AS totalUsers FROM User u)")`

Comment: you're not helping :D rephrase your question pls. you just copy pasted what written above, nothing new